# Extract filename

Tags: unix, sed

So I am new to SED and Unix and I would like to replace the following file:

```
1500:../someFile.C:111 error
1869:../anotherFile.C:222 error
1869:../anotherFile2.Cxx:333 error
//thousands of more lines with same structure
```

With the followig file

```
someFile.c
anotherFile.c
anotherFile2.Cxx
```

Basically, I just want to extract the filename from every line.

So far, I have read the documentation on sed and the second answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84922/extract-a-part-of-one-line-from-a-file-with-sed). My best  attempt was to use  a regex as follows:

```
sed "s/.\*\/.:.*//g" myFile.txt
```

Comment: Where do you cut (yes, you can use `cut` twice) ? Start after the last `/` until the last `:` ?

Comment: @user3586940  if any of the answer helped you then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this.

Sure, you could use `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^:]*://;s/:.*//;s#\.\./##' input.txt
sed 's%.*:\.\./\([^:]*\):.*%\1%' input.txt
```

Or you could use a series of `grep -o` instances in a pipe:

```
grep -o ':[^:]*:' input.txt | grep -o '[^:]\{1,\}' | grep -o '/.*' | grep -o '[^/]\{1,\}'
```

You could even use `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{sub(/\.\.\//,"",$2); print $2}' input.txt
```

But the simplest way would probably be to use `cut`:

```
cut -d: -f2 input.txt | cut -d/ -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the substring between last `/` and following `:` and replace the whole string with the captured string(`\1`).

```
sed  's#.*/\([^:]\+\).*#\1#g' myFile.txt
someFile.C
anotherFile.C
anotherFile2.Cxx
```

OR , with little less escaping, sed with `-r` flag.

```
sed -r 's#.*/([^:]+).*#\1#g' myFile.txt
```

Or if you want to use `grep`,this will only work if your `grep` supports `-P` flag which will enable `PCRE`:

```
grep -oP '.*/\K[^:]+' myFile.txt
someFile.C
anotherFile.C
anotherFile2.Cxx
```